# How to search a text which is displayed in the page content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
        if (searchTerm) {
            var selector = selector || "body";                             //use body as selector if none provided
            var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
            var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
            if (matches) {
                $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');     //Remove old search highlights
                $(selector).html($(selector).html()
                    .replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='highlighted'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
                if ($('.highlighted:first').length) {             //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                    $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').on("click", function () {
            if (!searchAndHighlight($('#txtSearch').val())) {
                alert("No results found");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In above code i have searched and highlighted  the text. But issue is if i type "in" it search whole page inner html and images. Screen short is given below.

How i search the text which is displayed in the page content.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use this plugin http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Comment: it doesnot worked for me

Comment: Any other solutions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/617348/How-to-search-text-from-page-with-next-and-previou
 I have completed my task using this plugin.

Comment: Thank you all  for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

So what i have thought of is `p`, `div` and `span` are the elements in which you should perform the check to find the substring.

```
  var search = ['p', 'div', 'span'];
  var pattern = searchTerm;

    $.each(search, function(i){
        var str = search[i];        
        var orgText = $(str).text();

        orgText = orgText.replace(pattern, function($1){
          return "<span class='highlighted'>" + $1 + "</span>"
        });

        $(str).html(orgText);
    });    
  });
```

Comment: replacing the `html` part with `text` might not help

Comment: RIght, it wont help, my bad.. :(

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: @void:The issue is i posted in the screen shot? it takes the text from asp.net hidden fields, text in images and all the letters in the body of html page.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for your use case so that i can play with it and let you know what is the exact thing you should do